# How do you install the FreeBSD10 kernel sources?

Tags: kernel, freebsd

I am trying to run an update of freebsd10 and I am being asked for the kernel sources

```
===>>> Launching child to update lsof-4.89.b,8 to lsof-4.89.d,8

===>>> All >> lsof-4.89.b,8 (9/9)

===>>> Currently installed version: lsof-4.89.b,8
===>>> Port directory: /usr/ports/sysutils/lsof

        ===>>> This port is marked IGNORE
        ===>>> requires kernel sources


        ===>>> If you are sure you can build it, remove the
               IGNORE line in the Makefile and try again.

===>>> Update for lsof-4.89.b,8 failed
===>>> Aborting update
```

but sysinstall no longer exist

```
sysinstall: not found
```

What is the new method of installing the kernel sources in FreeBSD10?

I thought bsdinstall, but it only tries to chop up my disk which I do not want  [image]

Comment: You're fairly evidently _not_ updating FreeBSD if you are upgrading a third-party port by the name of `sysutils/lsof`.  Even aside from the fact that this is happening in `/usr/ports`, the actual FreeBSD operating system command is `fstat`.  Which are you _actually_ trying to do: upgrade the ports collection? or upgrade the operating system?  Because they are two different answers and two different chapters of the _FreeBSD Handbook_.  Yes, this is all in the _Handbook_.

Comment: lsof was looking for them and I really just wanted them. I am not shy about a kernel, but the info is no where to be found. Just getting the current kernel sources.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it:

```
git clone https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd.git /usr/src
cd /usr/src; make clean
```

Comment: For future searchers, this will pull down a *significant* amount of additional data (git stuff) that's not needed for actual building from source. J. Delgado's answer is the canonical and most efficient method.

Answer (score 40):

You can manually download and extract a tarball of the full source tree for your specific release from ftp://ftp.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD/releases/

E.g.

> fetch ftp://ftp.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD/releases/amd64/***`10.2-RELEASE`***/src.txz
>
> tar -C / -xzvf src.txz
>
> ***`10.2-RELEASE`*** MUST be replaced with correct version of your OS.
>
> One can find version using command: ***`freebsd-version -k`***
>
> The minor versions should be ignored to fetch from the above URL. For ex: if it is ***`10.2-RELEASE-p1`***, just use: ***`10.2-RELEASE`***

Comment: This is the right answer.

Comment: Works with FreeBSD 11.2.

Comment: Note that the `-z` option is unnecessary here, as tar will autodetect the input format. Per the man page, `In extract or list modes, this option is ignored.` I also like doing this inline: `fetch -o- ftp://ftp.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD/releases/amd64/X.Y-RELEASE/src.txz | sudo tar -C / -xvf -`. No need to store `src.txz` locally.

Answer (score 14):

A bit more generic solution:

```
fetch -o /tmp ftp://ftp.freebsd.org/pub/`uname -s`/releases/`uname -m`/`uname -r | cut -d'-' -f1,2`/src.txz

tar -C / -xvf /tmp/src.txz
```

And you can replace `/tmp` with your favorite directory to download things into.

Or:

```
svn checkout https://svn.freebsd.org/base/releng/`uname -r | cut -d'-' -f1,1` /usr/src
```