# FreeBSD: everything exited on signal 12 after "make buildworld"

Tags: permissions, freebsd, make, signals, source

I downloaded and compiled the source code of FreeBSD with:

```
git clone https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd.git /usr/src
cd /usr/src
make clean
make buildworld
```

and literally *everything* would exit on signal 12. I tried `reboot`ing the system, but `reboot` exited on signal 12, so I had to press the power button to shutdown my device. When I boot to FreeBSD again, I can't even login. Firstly it tells me

> Jun  4 08:10:32 init: /bin/sh on /etc/rc terminated abnormally, going to single user mode
>   Enter full pathname of shell or RETURN for /bin/sh:

And if I send a RETURN, an error would occur:

> **pid 33 (sh), uid 0: exited on signal 12**
>   Jun  4 08:10:51 init: single user shell terminated, restarting
>   Enter full pathname of shell or RETURN for /bin/sh:

The worst thing about this problem is that the same error occurs even when I enter Single User Mode.

How can I fix this?

Comment: https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/makeworld.html shows other steps, such as `make kernel` though I don't see where you ran `installworld` to install things? What exact steps did you follow?

Comment: @thrig I wasn't follow any steps. Actually, I just needed to download the source code, so that a [`===> bwn-firmware-kmod-0.1.2 requires kernel source files in /usr/src` error](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/367591/158931#comment-655674) can be solved. However, after downloading the source, I thought "since I have the source code, why not compile them?", so I ran `make buildworld`, and everything `exited on signal 12`...

Comment: Suggest you try to boot in to safe mode. If that fails you should be able to rescue the drive contents with a Live CD of some sort. Personally I've had some pretty major issues but nothing that stopped single user mode except a few failed drives. Also [read the handbook](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/makeworld.html) :]

Comment: This is likely due to the kernel and userland being out of sync. Boot from a Live CD and download/compile a new kernel first.

Comment: Maybe you are out of the disk space?

Comment: @arrowd I don't think so, because I had ~50GB of free disk space before `make buildworld` started.

Comment: @Tigger Tried booting into safe mode, which didn't help. Seems that I really screwed up :(

Comment: @Kusalananda OK I've managed to boot into a live CD, but it doesn't contain any compiler! `cc`, `gcc`, `clang`, all of those just don't exist. I tried to install it with `pkg`, but it told me "A pre-built version of pkg could not be found for your system". Any suggestions for this situation?

Comment: @Tigger Now I'm [having some problems](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/369151/158931) rescuing the drive contents with a Live CD. Could you please give me a hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had a bad luck to upgrade your system at a very rare moment of the CURRENT branch changing its ABI, *and* ignore the safe procedure detailed here (the 20170523 entry):

https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/blob/master/UPDATING

At this point - old kernel, new userland, which is the only unsupported configuration there is (new kernel, old userland is fine) - I'd say the easiest way out is to reinstall, without reformatting partitions.