# Cannot build source from FreeBSD live CD

Tags: freebsd, make, source, livecd, compiler

I screwed up my FreeBSD system, so I'm going to fix it from a FreeBSD live CD.

First, I boot into the live CD, mount the partition where the broken system resides in with `mount -t ufs /dev/ada0p5 /mnt`, and used `ls /mnt` to verify everything went as expected.

Then I `cd /mnt/usr/src`, and `make clean`, but it told me `sh: cc: not found`.

Other compilers, such as `gcc` and `clang`, aren't available in live CD too. I tried to install them with `pkg`, but `pkg` isn't available either.

Please help me out.

Comment: Need more info, but this is my suggestion. Backup everything you need. Reinstall FreeBSD, restore from backup.

Comment: @Tigger That sounds bad...but thanks!

Comment: It may sound like a daunting task, but honestly it is a lot quicker than you think. If you have partitioned the drive to system and userland it is only the system that needs to be reinstall (but backup everything just in case). If you have physical access to your system, use another drive to backup (internal or external). If it is a remote box (does not sound like it) backup to a remote site or pull the backup down. Couple of hours at a best guess.

Comment: Cc and such aren't in your path, as they're all at /mnt/ instead of their usual locations.