# Configuring BCM4360 (MacBook Air) on FreeBSD to connect to WiFi

Tags: wifi, freebsd, macintosh, broadcom, wlan

I just installed FreeBSD 12.1 RELEASE on my MacBook Air 13-inch Early 2015, and one of the notable problems is the lack of WiFi due to the `bwn` kernel module not being loaded. I loaded it and told the `/boot/loader.conf` to load it at boot, rebooted, and it did not work. I checked `ifconfig` but only loopback was shown.

Output of `pciconf -lv` says the network adapter is a BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter. How can I configure it to work?

Comment: I think it's https://superuser.com/ question

Comment: I cannot find much online about "BWM4360 802.11ac". Are you sure that's the correct name of the device?

Comment: Sorry it’s actually called a BCM4360

Comment: Related: [FreeBSD cannot use WiFi with BCM4360 on MacBook Air](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/367591/80216).

Answer (score 3):

Have you taken a look at the [manual page for bwn(4)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?bwn)<sup>1</sup>? It mentions that bwn devices need firmware to be loaded.

### Installing firmware

Firmware for those devices is available as a port called [`net/bwn-firmware-kmod`](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/). Due to license reasons, there is no binary package available for this port via [pkg(8)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?pkg), so it has to be installed from [ports(7)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ports&sektion=&n=1) by the user with something like:

```
cd /usr/ports/net/bwn-firmware-kmod && make install
```

Please refer to the [*Using the Ports Collection*](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/ports-using.html) chapter of the [FreeBSD Handbook](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/) for more details on how to work with ports.

### What if I do not have network connection on the machine at all?

Of course, it gets tricky to do it if you do not have access to the network from that machine. In this case, you could do the following:

On another FreeBSD machine which is connected to the network, run the following command.

```
cd /usr/ports/net/bwn-firmware-kmod && make -DFORCE_PACKAGE package
```

This command will generate a package (which will be located in `/usr/ports/head/net/bwn-firmware-kmod/work/pkg/bwn-firmware-kmod-0.1.2.txz`) for you.

It can be then copied to the disconnected laptop (with a USB stick for example) and installed with `tar -x -f ./bwn-firmware-kmod-0.1.2.txz`<sup>2</sup>.

---

<sub>**1**: Assuming that *bwm* is just a typo.</sub>

<sub>**2**: It would be much better to install the package with `pkg` but the real [pkg(8)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=pkg&apropos=0&sektion=8&manpath=FreeBSD+12.1-RELEASE+and+Ports&arch=default&format=html) which is the package manager on FreeBSD has to be bootstrapped with [pkg(7)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=pkg&apropos=0&sektion=7&manpath=FreeBSD+12.1-RELEASE+and+Ports&arch=default&format=html). It is doable without network connection, but probably unnecessarily complicated in your case.</sub>

Comment: I can’t use the ports collection, it fetches the source code from the internet. And I meant BCM4360

Comment: @Dvonik: I've update the answer.

Comment: @Dvonik `pkg` is fetched from the internet, too, so I don't understand why you can't use ports.

Answer (score 0):

The `bwn-firmware-kmod`-port does not appear to support BCM4360 at the moment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/465292/243368